# LISP: The value is not of the expected type LIST

Tags: types, lisp, common-lisp

I'm incredibly new to coding in LISP, and I'm trying to write this preliminary snippet of code to read words from a file into a parameter, then print out all of the words from that list to make sure all of the words were put into it. This is what I have so far:

```
(defparameter *wordlist* nil)

(defun run()
  (get-words-from-file)
  (print-wordlist *wordlist*))

(defun get-words-from-file ()
  (let ((in (open "/Users/levibanks/Desktop/cs352/program3/wordlist.txt")))
    (dotimes (n 500)
      (setq *wordlist* (append (read-line in))))
  (close in)))

(defun print-wordlist (wordlist)
  (when wordlist
    (print (car wordlist))
    (print-wordlist (cdr wordlist))))
```

When I try to run this code though, it gives me the error "The value 'brown' [a word in the file i'm reading out of] is not of the expected type LIST."

I'm really not sure why this shouldn't work as this is how I've seen lists printed out before, so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You should read up on

- [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm)
- [`push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm)
- [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm)

In particular, `(setq a (append b))` does *not* append anything to the previous value of `a`.

What you need is

```
(defun read-lines-from-file (file-name)
  (with-open-file (input file-name)
    (loop for line = (read-line input nil nil)
       while line collect line)))

(defparameter *wordlist* (read-lines-from-file "/Users/levibanks/Desktop/cs352/program3/wordlist.txt"((
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I realized after I posted this that I wasn't using append correctly because (A) the word that I was reading in from the file wasn't considered a list, and (B) I wasn't giving append two parameters (namely *wordlist* and the read-line).

Comment: `(defun get-words-from-file ()
  (let ((in (open "/Users/levibanks/Desktop/cs352/program3/wordlist.txt")))
    (dotimes (n 500)
      (setq *wordlist* (append *wordlist* (list (read-line in)))))
    (close in)))`